# Python: Why is my code not cropping a selected image properly?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to write a python program which crops the image in order to remove the extra white spaces. For this I'm traversing the whole image to look for left most, right most, top most and bottom most pixel to identify the necessary boundaries for cropping. My code misses some pixels on the left, right and bottom boundaries. The first image given is the source image and the other one is the resultant image.

[image]

[image]

Here's my code:

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image
import os

bw = Image.open('abw.png')
width, height = bw.size
top, bottom, left,right = 100,-10,100,-10 #The given image 90x90
for x in range(height):
    for y in range(width):
        if(bw.getpixel((x,y))<255):
            #if black pixel is found
            if(y<left):
                left = y
            if(y>right):
                right = y
            if(x<top):
                top = x
            if(x>bottom):
                bottom = x

bw.crop((left,top,right,bottom)).save('abw1.png')
```

Can someone figure out the problem in my code?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the for loop there? Could you elaborate on the same?

Comment: For loop traverses through the image and looks for useful boundaries values. As you can see in this image that it has unnecessary extra white spaces around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture you uploaded is a JPG, not a PNG, so there could be some decoding artifacts in it what makes
the algorithm confuse a very light gray pixel with a black one. Therefore, I introduced a threshold value.

The main problem seems to be that you swapped **x** and **y**.

I cleaned up some formatting (PEP8).

The code below works pretty well on your test image (saved as a JPG).

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image

threshold = 220 # Everything below threshold is considered black.

bw = Image.open('abw.jpg')
width, height = bw.size
top = bottom = left = right = None
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        if bw.getpixel((x,y)) < threshold:
            # if black-ish pixel is found
            if (left is None) or (x < left):
                left = x
            if (right is None) or (x > right):
                right = x
            if (top is None) or (y < top):
                top = y
            if (bottom is None) or (y > bottom):
                bottom = y

im = bw.crop((left, top, right + 1, bottom + 1))
im.show()
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked! But why did you increment right and bottom by 1?

Comment: Because I was under the impression that otherwise the rightmost column and bottom row weren't included in the cropped image. The variable 'bottom' will contain the y coordinate of the lowest row where a black pixel was found, and the fact that it has a black pixel means that you want that row in the output.